# changing the background of a received and sent message in recyclerview (firebase)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

iam trying to change the background image of imageview accordion to who sent the message 
if it was me then the background be my pic 
if it was the other the background become anonymous 
the problem is 
my code is working but
sometimes its changing like 
i means lets say that the background of sent message is green and the received is yellow
sometimes the sent be yellow and the received be green
and when i make refresh for the layout
its working perfectly 
so here is my code

First my recyclerview

```
private void intitializingRecyclerView()
{

    mMessagesList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    Query mQuery = mMyMessagesRef;

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions mOptions = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Message>()
            .setQuery(mQuery,Message.class).build();


    mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Message, MessagesHolder>(mOptions) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MessagesHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Message model) {
            if (model.getFrom().equals(myId))
            {
                holder.fillSentMessage(Image,model.getMessages());
            } else if (!model.getFrom().equals(myId))
            {
                holder.fillReceivedMessage("",model.getMessages());
            }
            holder.showElements();
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public MessagesHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

             View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rv_sent_message,parent,false);
            return new MessagesHolder(view,parent.getContext());
        }
    };
    mMessagesList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}
```

then my sendButton what i wrote in it is just this

```
mMessage.setText("");
mMessagesList.scrollToPosition(count - 1);
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and my HolderClass

```
public class MessagesHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private CircleImageView mImage;
    private TextView mMessage;
    private ConstraintLayout mLayout;

    Context context;

    public MessagesHolder(@NonNull View itemView, Context context) {
        super(itemView);
        this.context = context;

        mImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_sent_message);
        mMessage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_sent_message);
        mLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cl_message_layout);

    }


    public void fillSentMessage(final String Image, String Message) {
        Picasso.get().load(Image).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).into(mImage, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {
                Picasso.get().load(Image).into(mImage);
            }
        });
        mMessage.setText(Message);
    }

    public void fillReceivedMessage(final String Image, String Message) {

        mLayout.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR);
        if (!Image.isEmpty()) {

            Picasso.get().load(Image).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).into(mImage, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Exception e) {
                    Picasso.get().load(Image).into(mImage);
                }
            });
        } else
        {
            Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.anynomous).into(mImage);
        }
        mMessage.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        mMessage.setText(Message);
        mMessage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.recieved_message);

    }

    public void showElements()
    {
        mMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

}
```

thank you

Comment: Canh you please explain what `the background of sent message is green and the received is yellow sometimes the sent be yellow and the received be green` mean?

Comment: thanks for your comment .. a small example of what i want to do is like messenger app or whats app .. when u send a message its became in a color and when u receive a message its became in another color .. thats what i want to do in my app and the code is working .. but the problem sometimes its become the oppesite so instead of the sent message be in yellow its become in green and when i do refresh for the recyclerview .. its become yellow again

Comment: Try calling `holder.showElements();` method before setting data that is before `if` condition.  Not sure if that'll work.

Comment: thanks i solved it by adding an another if statement that checking if the code is equal my friend code

Answer (score 0):

thanks i solved it by adding an another if statement that checking if the code is equal my friend code

```
 if (model.getFrom().equals(myId))
                {
                    holder.fillSentMessage(Image,model.getMessages());
                } else if (model.getFrom().equals(friendId))
                {
                    holder.fillReceivedMessage("",model.getMessages());
                }
                holder.showElements();}
```